# Revisiting Old Material

Tags: soft-question

Due to certain reasons i am often compelled to take sporadic breaks say ($1-2$  weeks) in studying mathematics, owing to which i am confronted with the problem of recalling past material. Given this context how should one proceed?

- Completely review all prior material A-Z ? or
- Look up material as is necessary to solve the problems in which there is a possibility of something being missed out.

**PS:** I know my question is not specifically about mathematics per se and is thus perhaps subject to closure but this happens to me quite often is therefore a substantial nuisance. I therefore appeal especially to the more experienced math folks in the community to suggest a resonable solution.

Regards and thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think there's a good answer to this. Every person has different study habits. If ad-hoc lookups suffice for your needs, great! Otherwise, a deeper review might be necessary.